# How to call a promise on every value of an array sequentially?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an array of values and I want to call a promise function on every value of the array. But this has to happen sequentially. I also want to wait calling the next promise before the previous promise is resolved.

```
let array = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  MyPromiseFunction(array[i]).then(
     // goToNextPromise
  );
}
```

Comment: There **has** to be a dupetarget for this, but I haven't found it yet... (Edit: Found it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `Array#reduce` approach:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
array.reduce((p, value) => {
    return p.then(() => MyPromiseFunction(value));
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce()` for this:

```
let array = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

let p = array.reduce(function (p, e) {
    return p.then(function () {
        return MyPromiseFunction(e);
    });
}, Promise.resolve());
```